# How to play an animation frames for once each time?-LibGdx

Tags: java, animation, libgdx

I'm using an animation with 6 frames in my game for an event. It has a fixed order to be played.

```
Array<TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion> anim=new Array<TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion>();
anim =  game.playAtlas.findRegions(RegionNames.FEATHER_ANIMATION);
TextureRegion[] ftr = {anim.get(0),anim.get(1),anim.get(2),anim.get(3),anim.get(4),anim.get(5)};

featherAnimation = new Animation(0.1f,ftr);
featherAnimation.setPlayMode(PlayMode.NORMAL);
```

I want to run this animation only once(that means it should play 0th frame to 
 last frame and then should stop),when a particular boolean is true.

After playing the last frame,It should stop and make the boolean false also.

Like this I did

```
if (featherBool && egg.isEggAtNest()) {
  featherTexture = featherAnimation.getKeyFrame(animationTime, true);
  batch.draw(featherTexture, egg.getX() - featherTexture.getRegionWidth() / 2, fx.getY());
  featherBool = false;
}
```

But this is not achieving what I want.

The frames are not in the order I specified.
Also, how can I stop the animation once it plays 0 to 5<sup>th</sup> frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use in this way :

```
if (featherBool) {  
    animationTime+=.01f;
    featherTexture = featherAnimation.getKeyFrame(animationTime);  // <--looping not required so remove second argument
    batch.draw(featherTexture, egg.getX() - featherTexture.getRegionWidth() / 2, fx.getY());
    if(featherAnimation.isAnimationFinished(animationTime))
        featherBool = false;
}
```

Call `showAnimation()` method

```
private void showAnimation(){

    featherBool=true;
    animationTime=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using your `animationTime`  value for other Animations?
If yes, you should set it to 0, before playing `featherAnimation`.

```
if (somethingToRunfeatherAnimation) {
   animationTime = 0;
   featherBool = true;
}
```

Also this snippet will run only once because you set `featherBool = false`  at once.

```
if (featherBool && egg.isEggAtNest()) {
   featherTexture = featherAnimation.getKeyFrame(animationTime, true);
   batch.draw(featherTexture, egg.getX() - featherTexture.getRegionWidth() / 2, fx.getY());
   featherBool = false;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
if (featherBool && egg.isEggAtNest() && !featherAnimation.isAnimationFinished(animationTime) {
   featherTexture = featherAnimation.getKeyFrame(animationTime); // deleted looping
   batch.draw(featherTexture, egg.getX() - featherTexture.getRegionWidth() / 2, fx.getY());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The render code is called only once

```
if (featherBool && egg.isEggAtNest()) {
   featherTexture = featherAnimation.getKeyFrame(animationTime, true);
   batch.draw(featherTexture, egg.getX() - featherTexture.getRegionWidth() / 2, fx.getY());
   featherBool = false; ///   The render code is called only once
}
```

You must raise time too.

```
stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
```

Before you false the featherBool value, you must place the animation endpoint

```
if( yourAnimation.isAnimationFinished( stateTime ) )
        featherBool = false;
```